# How to use char index in dynamic sql

Tags: dynamic-sql

As I am new to dynamic SQL, can you please help me with the below query?

```
((LEFT(UF.PostCode, CHARINDEX(' ', UF.PostCode)) = ANY(SELECT * FROM @PostCodes) AND UF.IsEuropean = 0))
```

Here `@PostCodes` is declared as a temporary table (like - `DECLARE @PostCodes TABLE`)

- `UF.IsEuropean` column name and uf is the aliases name
- `UF.PostCode` column name and uf is the aliases name

Comment: How to modify the query (mentioned above) to dynamic sql

Comment: Dynamic SQL is highly dependent on the database product being used. "SQL" is just a query language. So which DBMS product are you using? (the `@` seems to indicate SQL Server with T-SQL)